# Can US based company publish on Huawei AppGallery?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, appgallery, appgallery-connect

I have been researching online but I cannot find a clear statement. Is a US-based company allowed to publish apps on Huawei App Store or does the ban forbid it?

Answer (score 1):

The following table describes whether the services of registration, identity verification, Merchant Service, Payment Service, and Account Service are supported in each country or region for enterprise developers. A check (√) indicates that the service is supported.

[image]

We can see that Huawei does not ban forbid on US-based company enterprise developers. US enterprises support account registration, which means they can release applications.

For details about the application release process and specifications, see:

[Official website](http://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/).

[Creating an App](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/agc-help-createapp-0000001146718717).

[Copyright Qualification Review Requirements](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/30215).

Comment: Thanks! I didn't mean to ask if Huawei bans it, I would like to know if US law forbids it.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can if you get Copyright Certificate in china. But how to do that ? Well probably best would be to pay some chinese company for that so they basically will have copyright registered on them, otherwise looks like not so easy, because of great bureaucratic wall of China.

This is good guide that actually explains it quickly:

> 1. Can I get a Software Copyright Certificate if I’m not a Chinese company?
>
> Yes, the copyright owner can be a foreign company or legal person, but
> you must submit the legal proof certified by the local Chinese
> consulate or notarized by the local notary office.

So basically you can and cannot, means that you cannot on your own, you need someone from china to help you. I believe that was their intention to make it more difficult for foreigners and more profitable for china businesses. And also let's not forget number of other special rules you have to obey in terms of app user interface and functionality to be accepted on mainland China.

https://medium.com/huawei-developers/the-ultimate-guide-to-register-software-copyright-certificates-in-china-45571448fc9f